# Using jQuery validator plugin on dynamically generated bootstrap-modal is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, datatables

I'm trying to validate inputs in a dynamically created bs-modal, but it isn't working at all. I don't get any errors and it seems that it doesn't try to validate the input at all.

Creating the bs-modal:

```
var data = "";

          data += "<form name='altEditor-form' role='form'>";

          for(var j = 0; j < columnDefs.length; j++){
            data += "<div class='form-group'><div class='col-sm-3 col-md-3 col-lg-3 text-right' style='padding-top:7px;'><label for='" + columnDefs[j].title + "'>" + columnDefs[j].title + ":</label></div><div class='col-sm-9 col-md-9 col-lg-9'><input type='text'  id='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' name='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' placeholder='" + columnDefs[j].title + "' style='overflow:hidden'  class='form-control  form-control-sm' value=''></div><div style='clear:both;'></div></div>";

          }
          data += "</form>";


          $('#altEditor-modal').on('show.bs.modal', function() {
            $('#altEditor-modal').find('.modal-title').html('Add Record');
            $('#altEditor-modal').find('.modal-body').html('<pre>' + data + '</pre>');
            $('#altEditor-modal').find('.modal-footer').html("<button type='button' data-content='remove' class='btn btn-default' data-dismiss='modal'>Close</button>\
               <button type='button' data-content='remove' class='btn btn-primary' id='addRowBtn'>Add Record</button>");
          });

          $('#altEditor-modal').modal('show');
          $('#altEditor-modal input[0]').focus();
```

I would like to do add the validation code to the free datatable editor that I'm re-writing which is why I use the $.getScript function, but i have also tried to run the validate-code in the  section of the index.html file, which doesn't work either.

The validator code:

```
$.getScript("libs/jquery-validation-1.15.0/dist/jquery.validate.js", function(data, textStatus){
   console.log("Loading Script..");
   console.log(textStatus);


$("#altEditor-form").validate({
    rules: {
    "NTP Server": {
      required: true,
      serverText: true
    }
  },
});
jQuery.validator.addMethod('serverText', function(value){
  return /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test(value);
}, "Invalid address.");

});
```

I have double checked and both the name of the form and the name of the input to validate is set correct. I am also sure that the script is loaded in the $.getScript, so I am not really sure why it isn't working.

Comment: when `$("#altEditor-form").validate({..})` is executed, whether the dynamic form is already created

Comment: @ArunPJohny I'm not sure what you mean, but i have tried to put the validator code into a function and calling that function when the "addRowBtn" is clicked. Result is the same and nothing happens.